# Always embed a hidden invisible product to cart

Tags: product, cart

I want to co-opt my ultimo-shop, therefore I need a solution for an always fixed, invisible product (Price: 0 € in the cart).
The customer should not see this product.

This product must be always there, not only after clicking an url (I tried the extension salgua, which works fine, but not for my problem).

I already found out, how to make the first product in my cart invisible in the fronted.
(CSS, display:none).
But now I don´t know, how to place the product always fixed in the cart.

Has anybody any idea?
Thank you,
Sara

Answer (score 2):

this is something I would recommend to do using an extension. if you hide something using css a user could easily manipulate that.

I don't quite understand why you want to do this but if I had to implement this it would be through an observer which is triggered before an order is placed (after the user clicks on the order button). The observer would add the product just before it is stored. You just have to make sure there are no conflicts with shipping or payment methods.

But still this feels weird... whats the goal you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a customer who wants to add a paper catalog to every order ;)

Comment: @greenone83 I know, it sounds a bit weird. Sorry for that. I will use my cart as a "request for quote" tool. The user should have the option, to choose a particular product ("add to cart" is named in "add to price request list"). Additionally the user should have the possibility, to send a "price request" (original:place order) with a free text field without choosing a product. But in this case, the order could not be placed due to the fact, that the user has´t added a product to cart. Therefore I need to place a fixed, hidden product in every cart. Hope that´s a bit more clearly ;)

Comment: @greenone83 ah, I forgot : I use 0-Step-Checkout, there is my required comment-field already embed. Now I only need a invisible, always placed product in the cart.

Comment: in that case you need an observer who checks the cart and (if missing) adds the placeholder-product. you will have to call this observer based on multiple events to make sure its always there. And i also recommend to hide the product programmatically in the cart template.